# Convert TRANSFORM Access Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, pivot, transform

I am looking to convert the below TRANSFORM statement from Access to SQL Server.

```
TRANSFORM case when sum(a.RE_Amt) = NUll then 0
    when sum(a.RE_Amt) is NUll then 0
    else sum(a.RE_Amt) end as AJE_AmountAS Restated_Amount
 SELECT A.Deal, A.Entity, A.StatementDate, A.From_Date, A.To_Date, 
 A.PostingDate, A.CUSIP, A.AME
 FROM (SELECT tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.deal, tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.Entity, 
 tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.statementdate, tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.From_Date, 
 tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.To_Date, tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.PostingDate, 
 tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.CUSIP, tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.Orig_Amt, 
 tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.Re_Amt, tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.AJE_Amt, 
 tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.Type, tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.AME
 FROM tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL
 where tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.deal like '*2010-R3*'
 and tbl_CUSIP_Compare_ALL.PostingDate = #5/31/2015 #)  AS A
 GROUP BY A.Deal, A.AME, A.Entity, A.StatementDate, A.From_Date, 
 A.To_Date, A.PostingDate, A.CUSIP, A.AME
 PIVOT A.Type;
```

I am unable to find a way to do this. Any help is apprecaited!

Comment: This is SQL. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: TRANSFORM does not work in SQL server - only in access. I am trying to Pivot on Type so the Type will be in columns to show the RE_Amount in the Type column.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) keyword for sql server?